# PHP/MYSQL live search with multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How do you carry out a PHP/MySQL live search (i.e. returning the results without refreshing) with multiple fields?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific with a coding problem to get more help than "yes, use AJAX for that".

Answer (score 0):

You mean auto suggest system. The small example is http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp .